# How to benchmark redis with jmeter?

Tags: groovy, redis, jmeter, jedis

I want to loadtest redis with jmeter. I found the 'redis data set' plugin for jmeter, but it's only for testing with datatype 'set', isn't it? I have a datamodel with datatype hash. So my data looks like

```
user:1 field1 value1 ... fieldn valuen
...
user:n field1 value1 ... fieldn valuen
```

So in jmeter I configured a JSR223Sampler with groovy-script:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(IP, port);
String result = jedis.hget("user:1", "prop1");
SampleResult.setResponseData(result.toString().getBytes());
```

Error message is like "Can't resolve class Jedis". I already downloaded the jedis.jar-File and put it in jmeter/lib.

So to wrap it up: How can I loadtest redis with jmeter using datatype hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't auto recognize Objects from different jars added to its lib folder,

You must add import statement, in your case:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
```